# Xcode 6.3.2 or 6.4beta Localization failed to read a strings file

Tags: ios, swift, localization, xcode6

Yes, I know there are many discussions about this failure. But after checking them out, I think what I have now is different.

In here [Error while "Export For Localization.." Xcode 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611456/error-while-export-for-localization-xcode-6-3), it says the single quote (') should be replaced as (\') in the strings file.

In here [Xcode 6 localization failed to read a strings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161694/xcode-6-localization-failed-to-read-a-strings-file), it says that the NSLocalizedString should be commented out (if I understand it right).

To test the problem, I created a new project with 6.3.2 and 6.4(6E23). I can have single quotes in the strings file, but as long as there is NSLocalizedString (e.g. `var str = NSLocalizedString("Hi", tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "Hi", comment: "Hi")`) in the view controller file, the Xcode always pops up with 
[image]

Then I did

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath ./xliff -project testtest.xcodeproj -exportLanguage en
```

and I get

> Bad entry in file ViewController.swift (line = 26): Argument is not a literal string.
>
> 2015-06-15 11:08:22.177 xcodebuild[31272:1150546]
>
> [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/Localization/IDELocalizationWork.m:434
>
> Details:  Failed to read strings file
>   "/var/folders/1s/_d08hx4j2gn9t6wlrc5_7gq00000gn/T/Xcode3SourceStringsAdaptor-48CAE246-EBA5-4326-B3C5-B5032A4027D8/Localizable.strings",
>   underlying error:
>
> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
>
> Object:   IDELocalizationWork
>
> Method:  +readStringsWorkForContext:
>
> Thread:   {number = 1, name = main} Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
>
> xcodebuild: error: Localization failed to read a strings file

This error persists even if I comment out Line 26, which is

```
var str = NSLocalizedString("Hi", tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "Hi", comment: "Hi")
```

But if I delete Line 26, the error is gone.

So, I guese, the XLIFF generator somehow does not allow "NSLocalizedString" to appear whatsoever??

Have you ever found this like I did?

Answer (score 3):

There is a several problems, that cause this error:

#### 1. Empty `Localizable.strings` file.

**Solution:** Just add comment

```
    /** no localizable strings **/
```

to this file and problem is gone.

#### 2. The 2-nd problem in escape symbol: `\` (sometimes)

**Solution:** Remove it and figure out something with your special chars. And probably your export process will complete without errors.

Also `\` produce another bug:

Sting to export:

```
"ACCOUNT" = "Foo\\\'Bar\'bazz\"";
```

String after importing just recently exported file:

```
"ACCOUNT" = "\\''";
```

#### Bonus:

If you will try to import localization during exporting Xcode will **crash**!

*Welcome to localization hell by Apple!*

---

P.S.

- Still actual at least for `Version 6.4 (6E35b)`
- [Related openradar bug-report](https://openradar.appspot.com/21056545)

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case, after checking the /private/var/log/system.log, I realized one of our other programmers had saved one of the localization files in ASCII/Windows-1252, which was causing xcode to think the file was encoded in Shift JIS (or some other encoding). Saving the file in the proper encoding fixed things.

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem with Swift 3 on Xcode 8.1 because I had an extension

```
func  localized() -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: self)
}
```

I fixed it removing the extension and using directly NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""). I really don't know why the extension didn't work when I try to export the .xliff file.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue in Xcode 6.4 (6E35b). It appears related to including `bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()` parameter in the method call.

Taking that parameter out (it has a default value) appears to fix the error.

So change from this:

`var str = NSLocalizedString("Hi", tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "Hi", comment: "Hi")`

to this:

`var str = NSLocalizedString("Hi", tableName: nil, value: "Hi", comment: "Hi")`

This is obviously some kind of bug in Xcode's string localization scanner (I think it is a naive approach where they are expecting people to only use `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: comment)` and therefore expecting only strings as parameters to that method).

Comment: This worked for me. Removing the following **commented** line from my Objective-C project resulted in the xliffs being generated successfully.

`#define NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(key) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, @"NSDateTimeAgo", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NSDateTimeAgo.bundle"]], nil)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the same behavior whether or not the line is commented out is that localized string detection does not exclude comments and so your NSLocaluzedString call gets discovered and therefore your .strings file is processed and so on.

Comment: So this is bug or some kind of weird feature? To me, it looks like a buggy bug.

Comment: @ileonard looks like a bug to me as well. File a radar, perhaps Apple will notice.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by just redefining the `NSLocalizedString` function like that:

```
public func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: String = "", comment: String) -> String
{
    return yourBundleHere.localizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName)
}
```

Replace `yourBundleHere` with `NSBundle.mainBundle()` or what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, and it was because i used an apostroph charachter ' by in unicode format like this \U0027 and when i replaced the u char to small \u0027 the error message gone.

also, you must not comment NSLocalizedString because it hangs the parser, you must delete it from code.